# CNN Low test Accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-generation

I am building a CNN model to classify images into 11 classes as follows: 'dew','fogsmog','frost','glaze','hail','lightning','rain','rainbow','rime','sandstorm','snow'
and while training I get good accuracy and good validation accuracy

```html
Epoch 1/20
131/131 [==============================] - 1012s 8s/step - loss: 1.8284 - accuracy: 0.3724 - val_loss: 1.4365 - val_accuracy: 0.5719
Epoch 2/20
131/131 [==============================] - 67s 511ms/step - loss: 1.3041 - accuracy: 0.5516 - val_loss: 1.1048 - val_accuracy: 0.6515
Epoch 3/20
131/131 [==============================] - 67s 510ms/step - loss: 1.1547 - accuracy: 0.6161 - val_loss: 1.0509 - val_accuracy: 0.6732
Epoch 4/20
131/131 [==============================] - 67s 510ms/step - loss: 1.0681 - accuracy: 0.6394 - val_loss: 1.0644 - val_accuracy: 0.6616
Epoch 5/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 505ms/step - loss: 1.0269 - accuracy: 0.6509 - val_loss: 1.0929 - val_accuracy: 0.6363
Epoch 6/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 506ms/step - loss: 1.0018 - accuracy: 0.6576 - val_loss: 0.9666 - val_accuracy: 0.6869
Epoch 7/20
131/131 [==============================] - 67s 507ms/step - loss: 0.9384 - accuracy: 0.6790 - val_loss: 0.8623 - val_accuracy: 0.7144
Epoch 8/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 505ms/step - loss: 0.9160 - accuracy: 0.6903 - val_loss: 0.8834 - val_accuracy: 0.7180
Epoch 9/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 502ms/step - loss: 0.8909 - accuracy: 0.6915 - val_loss: 0.8667 - val_accuracy: 0.7050
Epoch 10/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 503ms/step - loss: 0.8476 - accuracy: 0.7075 - val_loss: 0.8100 - val_accuracy: 0.7339
Epoch 11/20
131/131 [==============================] - 67s 509ms/step - loss: 0.8108 - accuracy: 0.7262 - val_loss: 0.8352 - val_accuracy: 0.7137
Epoch 12/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 506ms/step - loss: 0.7922 - accuracy: 0.7212 - val_loss: 0.8368 - val_accuracy: 0.7195
Epoch 13/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 505ms/step - loss: 0.7424 - accuracy: 0.7442 - val_loss: 0.8813 - val_accuracy: 0.7166
Epoch 14/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 503ms/step - loss: 0.7060 - accuracy: 0.7579 - val_loss: 0.8453 - val_accuracy: 0.7231
Epoch 15/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 503ms/step - loss: 0.6767 - accuracy: 0.7584 - val_loss: 0.8347 - val_accuracy: 0.7151
Epoch 16/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 506ms/step - loss: 0.6692 - accuracy: 0.7632 - val_loss: 0.8038 - val_accuracy: 0.7346
Epoch 17/20
131/131 [==============================] - 67s 507ms/step - loss: 0.6308 - accuracy: 0.7718 - val_loss: 0.7956 - val_accuracy: 0.7455
Epoch 18/20
131/131 [==============================] - 67s 508ms/step - loss: 0.6043 - accuracy: 0.7901 - val_loss: 0.8295 - val_accuracy: 0.7477
Epoch 19/20
131/131 [==============================] - 66s 506ms/step - loss: 0.5632 - accuracy: 0.8018 - val_loss: 0.7918 - val_accuracy: 0.7455
Epoch 20/20
131/131 [==============================] - 67s 510ms/step - loss: 0.5368 - accuracy: 0.8138 - val_loss: 0.7798 - val_accuracy: 0.7549
```

but when I predict and submit my results I get very low accuracy.
here is my model

```
 from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 IMG_SIZE = 50

 datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,        
    validation_split=0.25)


 train_dataset = datagen.flow_from_directory(    directory=Train_folder,
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             target_size=(50,50), 
                                             subset="training",
                                             classes=['dew','fogsmog','frost','glaze','hail','lightning','rain','rainbow','rime','sandstorm','snow'],
                                             class_mode='categorical')

validation_dataset = datagen.flow_from_directory(  directory=Train_folder,
                                                    shuffle=True,
                                                    target_size=(50,50), 
                                                    subset="validation",
                                                    classes=['dew','fogsmog','frost','glaze','hail','lightning','rain','rainbow','rime','sandstorm','snow'],
                                                    class_mode='categorical')
```

```html
Found 4168 images belonging to 11 classes.
Found 1383 images belonging to 11 classes.
```

```
model = Sequential([
layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation="relu",padding='same',input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)),
layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'),
layers.Dropout(0.25),
layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu",padding='same'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'),
layers.Dropout(0.25),
layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu",padding='same'),
layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'),
layers.Dropout(0.4),
layers.Flatten(),
layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
layers.Dropout(0.3),
layers.Dense(11, activation='softmax')
])

model.build()
model.summary()
```

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
train_dataset,
epochs=20,
validation_data=validation_dataset,
 )
model.save('model.tfl')



Test_folder="/content/drive/MyDrive/[NN'22] Project Dataset/Test"
test_data = []
labels = []
for img in tqdm(os.listdir(Test_folder)):
  path = os.path.join(Test_folder, img)
  img_data2 = cv2.imread(path)
  try:
    img_data2 = cv2.resize(img_data2, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
  except:
    continue
  test_data.append([np.array(img_data2)])
  labels.append(img)

X_data=np.array([test_data]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
prediction = model.predict([X_data])
```

Comment: So and what accuracy do you get on your test data? Is your training dataset balanced?

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by balanced
I think it is the same as the training but without classes

Comment: I should predict the class of each image in the test directory and submit it as csv file.

Comment: Balanced means that your classes have roughly equal number of samples. In imbalanced datasets (if one of the classes has way more samples than others) "accuracy" metric gives erroneous results.

Comment: Okay I got it, the training samples are imbalanced. smallest class has 121 image and the largest one has 1059. How should I balance the data (how many samples should I take for each class.

Comment: I made all classes the same sample number. the accuracy increased when submitting the predicted values but still low the (0.675). Any other suggestions?

Comment: 0.675 on test data when validation data accuracy is 0.7549 is reasonable in my opinion. Is there a specific limit of test accuracy you're aiming for?

Comment: well it is a competition so I am trying to increase the accuracy as mush as I can